# Why ofstream::get() and put() cause lost information?

Tags: visual-c++

my function is copy2, i found function copy1 on cplusplus.com, i use copy2 and have a problem, but copy 1 is ok, copy2 cause loss information about atist, title, ... of the file mp3 for the test, i can not understand why?

```cpp
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void copy1()
{
    char * buffer;
    long size;

    ifstream infile ("Test.mp3",ifstream::binary);
    ofstream outfile ("Test2.mp3",ofstream::binary);

    // get size of file
    infile.seekg(0,ifstream::end);
    size=infile.tellg();
    infile.seekg(0);

    // allocate memory for file content
    buffer = new char [size];

    // read content of infile
    infile.read (buffer,size);

    // write to outfile
    outfile.write (buffer,size);

    // release dynamically-allocated memory
    delete[] buffer;
    cout<<"xong";
    outfile.close();
    infile.close();
    return ;
}
void copy2(){
    ifstream infile ("Test.mp3",ios::binary);
    ofstream outfile ("Test1.mp3",ios::binary);
    char c;
    while(!infile.eof())
    {
    infile.get(c);
    outfile.put(c);
    }
}
int main () {
    copy2();
}
```

Comment: How do you know that information is lost?  What program/tool/process are you using to determine that?

Answer (score 0):

Your `while(!infile.eof())` can cause trouble, as it can return faulty results under certain conditions.
I have had similar problems. Try to use something like this:

```
while (getline(infile,data))                                           
     {                                        
          cout<<data<<endl;
     }
```